# Alertdialog, separar el titulo del mensaje

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

estoy utilizando el tema Holo_Dialog en un AlertDialog, el problema es que el titulo me sale por debajo de la linea de separacion, como podria poner el titulo por encima?, o si utilizo el tema Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_MinWidth, como podria separar el titulo del menasaje? adjunto fotos

este es el alertDialog con el tema holo, como puedo hacer que el titulo salga por encima de la linea?

[image: este es el alertDialog con el tema holo]

este es el alertdialog con el tema Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_MinWidth, como puedo hacer que aparezca el titutulo y el texto separados por una linea?

[image: este es el alertdialog con el tema Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_MinWidth]

este es el codigo para el tema Theme_Holo_Dialog

```
   public void alertDialogExtraerBase() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog);
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.extraer);
        builder.setTitle("EXTRAER BASE?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setMessage("Se hara una copia de la base de datos, se guardara en la memoria interna del dispositivo, en la carpeta 'BACKUPSERIES'");
        builder.setPositiveButton("ACEPTAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                extraer.extraerbase(MainActivity.this);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("CANCELAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
```

este es el codigo para el tema Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_MinWidth

```
    public void alertDialogImportarBase() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_MinWidth);
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.importar);
        builder.setTitle("IMPORTAR BASE?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setMessage("Asegurate que tienes una copia de la base guardada en la carpeta 'BACKUPSERIES'");
        builder.setPositiveButton("ACEPTAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                importar.importarbase(MainActivity.this);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("CANCELAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
```

alguien me puede ayudar? gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parece que hay algún problema con ese theme que no permite que el titulo esté encima de la linea divisoria. Aún asi, se puede crear un layout especifico para ese o cualquier otro theme con una cabecera personalizada.

Para ello debes cambiar el `AlertDialog` para personalizarlo a tu gusto en el `MainActivity` de la siguiente manera:

```
// Tu constructora como la tenias
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog_MinWidth)
    .setTitle("EXTRAER BASE?")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setMessage("Se hara una copia de la base de datos, se guardara en la memoria interna del dispositivo, en la carpeta 'BACKUPSERIES'")
    .setPositiveButton("ACEPTAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            extraer.extraerbase(MainActivity.this);
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("CANCELAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

     }
});

// Asociamos el layout personalizado
Context mContext = builder.getContext();
LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
View mView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.cabezera_dialog, null);
TextView mTextView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
mTextView.setText("EXTRAER BASE?");
builder.setCustomTitle(mView);

// Quitamos la cabezera del propio AlertDialog
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
alertDialog.show();
```

Y creamos nuestro `cabezera_dialog.xml` personalizado:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Quedando el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y a partir de ahi se puede personalizar la cabezera en el layout que hemos creado (`cabezera_dialog.xml`) a nuestro gusto.

Esto es aplicable para cualquiera de los dos themes con los que tenias problemas y para cualquiera que deseemos.

Comment: Hola buenas, muchas gracias!!!